# Existence of global logarithm on manifolds

Tags: complex-analysis, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry

Consider we have a smooth map $f$ from a smooth manifold $M$ to $S^1$.

When can we find a global logarithm accordingly, i.e. a smooth map $g: M \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f=e^{ig}$? Any topological restriction we can give on $M$ to make this true? (e.g. simply-connected)

Comment: When the winding number of the image of any loop in $M$ is $0$. Being simply connected implies that.

Comment: The global lifting theorem (through theory of covering spaces) states that such a map exists iff the image of $\pi_1(M)$ in $\pi_1(S^1)$ is trivial. In particular, if there is no nontrivial map $\pi_1(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ (eg $\pi_1(M)$ is finite), it works.